# How do I retrieve data in jQuery for a flot pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flot, pie-chart

I am trying to retrieve data for a flot pie chart and want to make sure I am doing it correctly. Any feedback would be appreciated. I will also post my JSON data being returned to verify it has the proper syntax.

```
   <script src="js/flot/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
   <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
   #placeholder { width: 450px; height: 450px; }
   </style>    
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $.ajax({
        url:'../cgi-bin/bpo_piechart.cgi',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //alert("should be shown");
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    labelBoxBorderColor: "none"
                }
            });
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }

    });
 </script>
```

And my JSON data being churned out appears like the following: Can someone tell me if this is a problem? I think it's correct, but I might have to parse the quotes inside of the jQuery javascript block later.

```
[
   {
      "acctlocv":"CHE3",
      "percval":"3774"
   },
   {
      "acctlocv":"CMI-  CRL2",
      "percval":"5"
   },
   {
      "acctlocv":"CMI1",
      "percval":"4106"
   },
   {
      "acctlocv":"CMI2",
      "percval":"10259"
   },
   {
      "acctlocv":"CUST",
      "percval":"75"
   },
   {
      "acctlocv":"HELOCR",
      "percval":"6"
   },
   {
      "acctlocv":"Network",
      "percval":"8675"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's your JSON.  You need "label" and "data" instead of "acctlocv" and "percval".

```
         [
               {
                  "label":"CHE3",
                  "data":3774
               },
               {
                  "label":"CMI-  CRL2",
                  "data":5
               },
               {
                  "label":"CMI1",
                  "data":4106
               },
               {
                  "label":"CMI2",
                  "data":10259
               },
               {
                  "label":"CUST",
                  "data":75
               },
               {
                  "label":"HELOCR",
                  "data":6
               },
               {
                  "label":"Network",
                  "data":8675
               }
            ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyktLseo/1/

Edit - Raidri's comment is correct, 'data' can be strings and flot will convert.
http://jsfiddle.net/xyktLseo/2/

Comment: Correct (but strings as data are ok, flot will auto convert them).

Comment: Ok, thank you folks. I looked at that and wondered about that, but wasn't sure if I could name them label and data just within the javascript function block, or if I needed to do it in the Perl CGI array. I'll go back and fix that and check it! Many thanks to you both!

Comment: Well, the good news is that switch DID indeed allow the legend to get written! I'm getting an error about color expected but found none and expected end of value but found none. I'll try to work through that, though i do not have a designated color. I think I'll have to dynamically add that - does that sound correct? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to add a desinated color.  What does your option object look like now?  Add the updated code to your question (or ask a new question about this new problem)

Comment: Ok. Here is the revised code. 

    $.ajax({ url:'../network_cbr_orders/cgi-bin/bpo_piechart.cgi',
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", type: "POST", dataType: 'json', success: function (data) { //if (data > 3) { parseInt(data) //} alert ('array vals'+data); //return data; //JSON.parse(data,''); //alert("should be shown"); $.plot($("#placeholder"), parseInt(data), {..../

Comment: Sorry, the code was breaking, malformed, in my reply....I tried to properly indent it to show it as a code block.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't illustrate the problem at all.  You can't format code in a comment.  You can edit your original question or you can ask a new question (which is probably the better option).  Also, try your changes in the jsfiddle and see if they cause the problem there.